# Unable to Symbolicate crash Log on Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode

Installed xCode 7.3 on a fresh machine: OS 10.11.14.

While trying to run command:

```
sudo cp/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash
```

- always displays error - command not found

added directory:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
```

Comment: There is a space missing between `cp` and `/Applications/ ...`.

Comment: Or...why are you trying to use `cp` at all?